# Why can't I get to change the colour of my button?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, call

I'm programming a Samegame as a project for my studies on Python with Tkinter.
case is a 2 character code to identify the clicked square on my board ( A9 for instance )

This function:

```
l =(nb_ligne, nb_colonne, nb_couleurs, self.matrice_numbers, self.matrice_cellules)
def suppr_graph( l, case):
    for i in range(0, l[0]) :
        for j in range(0, l[1]) :
            if l[3][i][j] == case :
                couleur = l[4][i][j]
                l[4][i][j] = "X"
                verif_graph(l,i,j,couleur)
    for i in range(0, l[0]) :
        for j in range(0, l[1]) :
            if l[4][i][j] == "X":
                Alain_Devémy_Graphtest2.Board.colourize(i,j)
```

calls a function colourize in a second file, Alain_Devémy_Graphtest2, with a Board(TK) class, which goes as follows :

```
def colourize(i, j):
  b=Board.grid[i, j]
  b.config(bg='#000')
```

When I execute Alain_Devémy_Graphtest2.py, which is supposed to show the board importing functions from Noyal, my Kernel, i get the following error :

```
 b=Board.grid[i, j]
 TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's my Board class :

```
class Board(Tk):
"""a 6x6 board with clickable cells"""
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


def __init__ (self, nb_ligne, nb_colonne, nb_couleurs):
    self.nb_ligne = nb_ligne 
    self.nb_colonne = nb_colonne 
    self.nb_couleurs = nb_couleurs
    self.matrice_horizontale = [[True for col in range(self.nb_colonne)] for ligne in     range(self.nb_ligne+1)]
    self.matrice_verticale = [[True for col in range(self.nb_colonne+1)] for ligne in range(self.nb_ligne)]
    self.matrice_cellules = [[0 for col in range(self.nb_colonne)] for ligne in range(self.nb_ligne)]
    self.matrice_numbers= [[0 for col in range(self.nb_colonne)] for ligne in range(self.nb_ligne)]

    for i in range(0, self.nb_ligne):
        for j in range(0, self.nb_colonne):
            p = random.randint(0,(self.nb_couleurs)-1)
            self.matrice_cellules[i][j] = p

    lettre=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H", "I", "J"]      
    case=""
    p = 0
    for i in range(0, self.nb_ligne):
        for j in range(0, self.nb_colonne):              
            case+=lettre[j]
            case+=str(i)

            self.matrice_numbers[i][j] = case
            case=""
    print (self.matrice_cellules)
    print (self.matrice_numbers)
    """create 36 colored 'Button' widgets and pack them as a 6x6 grid"""
    colors = ('#F00', '#0F0', '#00F', '#FF0','#F0F', '#000')

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Tk.__init__(self)

    self.label = Label(self,  border=2, relief=SOLID) 
    self.label.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, pady=5, padx=5)
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.frame = Frame(self, border=2, relief=SOLID)
    self.frame.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.grid = {} 
    for n in range(nb_ligne*nb_colonne):         
      col, row = n%nb_colonne, n//nb_colonne          
      self.grid[row,col] = Button(self.frame, width=3, height=1, bg=colors[self.matrice_cellules[row ][col]], command = lambda : Alain_Devémy_Noyal.Kernel.callback(self,(nb_ligne, nb_colonne, nb_couleurs, self.matrice_numbers, self.matrice_cellules), self.matrice_numbers[row][col]))
      self.grid[row,col].grid(column=col, row=row)
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    self.colourize(0,0)
    self.title("Board"); self.resizable(0,0); self.mainloop();self.update()


def colourize(self,i,j):
  print(self.grid[0,1])

  self.grid[i,j].configure(bg="#FFF")
  #self.grid(row=i,column=j)
  #self.grid[i][j].config(bg="black")
  #b.config(bg='#FFF')





# ==============================================================================
def main() :
 a=int(input('Entrez le nombre de lignes'))
 b=int(input('Entrez le nombre de colonnes'))
 c=int(input('Entrez le nombre de couleurs'))
 board = Board(a, b, c)
 Noyau = Kernel(board)
 board.colourize(0,0)  

# ==============================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__": 
main()
```

And here's my Kernel class :

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import Alain_Devémy_Graphtest2
# ==============================================================================
class Kernel():

    def __init__(self,board):
            self.board = board

    def suppr(self,l,case):
            for i in range(0, l.nb_ligne) :
               for j in range(0, l.nb_colonne) :
                   if l.matrice_numbers[i][j] == case :


                       couleur = l.matrice_cellules[i][j]
                       l.matrice_cellules[i][j] = "X"
                       verif(l,i,j,couleur)




    # ==============================================================================
    def verif(self,l,i,j,couleur):
                    if(i>0):
                       if l.matrice_cellules[i-1][j] == couleur : #case au dessus
                           l.matrice_cellules[i-1][j] = "X"
                           verif(l,i-1,j,couleur)
                    if(j>0):
                       if l.matrice_cellules[i][j-1] == couleur : #case à gauche
                           l.matrice_cellules[i][j-1] = "X"
                           verif(l,i,j-1,couleur)
                    if(i<l.nb_ligne-1):
                       if l.matrice_cellules[i+1][j] == couleur : #case en dessous
                           l.matrice_cellules[i+1][j] = "X"
                           verif(l,i+1,j,couleur)
                    if(j<l.nb_colonne-1):
                       if l.matrice_cellules[i][j+1] == couleur : #case à droite
                           l.matrice_cellules[i][j+1] = "X"
                           verif(l,i,j+1,couleur)
    # ==============================================================================
    def gravity(self,l):

            for j in range(0, l.nb_colonne) :
                for i in range(l.nb_ligne-2, 0, -1) :

                    while l.matrice_cellules[i][j]!= "X" and l.matrice_cellules[i+1][j]== "X" :
                            for k in range(0, l.nb_colonne) :
                                for q in range(l.nb_ligne-1, 0, -1) :
                                    if l.matrice_cellules[q][k] == "X":
                                        l.matrice_cellules[q][k] = l.matrice_cellules[q-1][k]
                                        l.matrice_cellules[q-1][k] = "X"
                                for q in range(l.nb_ligne-1, 0, -1) :
                                    if l.matrice_cellules[q][k] == "X":
                                        l.matrice_cellules[q][k] = l.matrice_cellules[q-1][k]
                                        l.matrice_cellules[q-1][k] = "X"
                                for q in range(l.nb_ligne-1, 0, -1) :
                                    if l.matrice_cellules[q][k] == "X":
                                        l.matrice_cellules[q][k] = l.matrice_cellules[q-1][k]
                                        l.matrice_cellules[q-1][k] = "X"

            for j in range(0, l.nb_colonne) :
                if  l.matrice_cellules[l.nb_ligne-1][j]== "X" :
                    for k in range (j, l.nb_colonne-1) :
                        for q in range(0, l.nb_ligne) :
                            if  k == l.nb_colonne-1 :
                                    l.matrice_cellules[q][k] = "X"
                            else :
                                    l.matrice_cellules[q][k] = l.matrice_cellules[q][k+1]
                                    l.matrice_cellules[q][k+1] = "X"
    def suppr_graph(self,l, case):

              for i in range(0, l[0]) :
               for j in range(0, l[1]) :
                   if l[3][i][j] == case :
                       print('caca')
                       couleur = l[4][i][j]
                       print(couleur)
                       l[4][i][j] = "X"
                       print(l[4][i][j])
                       Kernel.verif_graph(self, l,i,j,couleur)
              for i in range(0, l[0]) :
               for j in range(0, l[1]) :
                       if  l[4][i][j] == "X":

                               print('lala')
                               Alain_Devémy_Graphtest2.Board.colourize(self,i,j)
      def gravity_graph(self,l):
             print(l[4])
             for j in range(0, l[1]) :
                for i in range(l[0]-2, 0, -1) : 
                    while l[4][i][j]!= "X" and l[4][i+1][j]== "X" :
                            for k in range(0, l[1]) :
                                for q in range(l[0]-1, 0, -1) :
                                   for l in range (0, 9):
                                           print (l[4])
                                             if str(l[4][q][k]) == "X":
                                                  l[4][q][k] = l[4][q-1][k]
                                                  l[4][q-1][k] = "X"


               for j in range(0, l[1]) :
                  if  l[4][l[0]-1][j]== "X" :
                      for k in range (j, l[1]-1) :
                          for q in range(0, l[0]) :
                              if  k == l[1]-1 :
                                      l[4][q][k] = "X"
                              else :
                                      l[4][q][k] = l[4][q][k+1]
                                      l[4][q][k+1] = "X"
             for j in range(0, l[1]) :
                  for i in range(l[0]-2, 0, -1) :
                          if l[4][i][j] == "X":
                                 print('lala')
                                 Alain_Devémy_Graphtest2.Board.colourize(self, i, j)
    def verif_graph(self,l,i,j,couleur):
                    if(i>0):
                       if l[4][i-1][j] == couleur : #case au dessus
                           l[4][i-1][j] = "X"
                           Kernel.verif_graph(self, l,i-1,j,couleur)
                    if(j>0):
                       if l[4][i][j-1] == couleur : #case à gauche
                           l[4][i][j-1] = "X"
                           Kernel.verif_graph(self, l,i,j-1,couleur)
                    if(i<l[0]-1):
                       if l[4][i+1][j] == couleur : #case en dessous
                           l[4][i+1][j] = "X"
                           Kernel.verif_graph(self,l,i+1,j,couleur)
                    if(j<l[1]-1):
                       if l[4][i][j+1] == couleur : #case à droite
                           l[4][i][j+1] = "X"
                           Kernel.verif_graph(self, l,i,j+1,couleur)
    # ==============================================================================
    def callback(self,l,  case):
        Kernel.suppr_graph(self, l, case)
        #Kernel.gravity_graph(self,l)
```

Could you Guys help me ? As I saw you were really efficient on other topics. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use the button's Tkinter Id.  See the config example at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm  It sets the relief instead of the background but you can use config to configure any of the options listed under config further down the page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
According to your piece of advice, I modified the program, obtaining the same error though

Comment: Ah yes, grid() is a geometry manager.  I assume, but don't know, that you have named something else "grid" which Tkinter thinks is the geometry manager function (function' object is not subscriptable).  What is the "grid" that you are using, and if it is not the geometry manager then you will have to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really useful to see the implementation of **Board**.

However, working with the info provided, there seems to be two issues here.

1. The error suggests that **Board.grid** is a function,
   so subscripting using a notation like **list[i]** won't work.
2. The subscripting looks like it's against
   standard Python notation, as a comma shouldn't really appear within
   the brackets when subscripting.

The most probable scenario is that you're simply trying to call a function, but used [] instead of (), and the fix is to swap

```
b=Board.grid[i, j]
```

with

```
b=Board.grid(i, j)
```

or at a stretch

```
b=Board.grid([i, j])
```

The latter being a call to **Board.grid** with a list of coordinates as the only argument.

Alternatively, if you meant to use subscripting, then **Board.grid** is probably supposed to be a nested list.  In that cast, the line needs to be

```
b=Board.grid[i][j]
```

This solution requires extensive reworking to change **Board.grid** into a nested list, instead of being a function as it currently is.

### **Update**

I hadn't thought about the case where **Board.grid** is a dictionary and you're sending tuples as the subscript via **Board.grid[i, j]**.

That's perfectly valid, so the only problem is that you're getting a naming conflict between the grid function as defined for the Tk class that Board inherits from, and the grid attribute you define as a dict of buttons.

Easiest solution is probably to rename your **Board.grid** as **Board.button_grid** or something similar to avoid this conflict.

Comment: I just added my Board composition, it's quite big I hope it's no problem